# Angular ActionCable call method in component when notification received

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angular, heroku, actioncable

I'm trying to practice using `ActionCable` in `Angular`.  I created a quick `Rails` application that I put up on `Heroku` and then created an `Angular` application with the `actioncable` npm module as a dependency.

I configured my `Rails` appplication to allow `http://localhost:4200` as an origin while I play around with my `Angular` app in development.  I also didn't make this an API application because I wanted to have a working UI from the get-go.  So I can log into the `Rails` application, send a message, and my separate `Angular` application is subscribed to that channel as well.  I'm successfully receiving those notifications/messages.

Now I'd like to render something in Angular based on that message.  I think I'm missing something pretty silly here, but I cannot refer to methods in the component that instantiates the subscription to that channel in the `receive` callback of the subscription.

```
import {
  ComponentFactoryResolver,
  ComponentRef,
  OnInit,
  ViewContainerRef,
  Component,
  ViewChild,
  Output
} from '@angular/core';
import * as ActionCable from 'actioncable';
import { MessageComponent } from 'app/message/message.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  messageRef: ComponentRef<MessageComponent>;
  @ViewChild('message', { read: ViewContainerRef }) message: ViewContainerRef;

  title = 'app works!';
  private cable: ActionCable.Cable;
  private subscription: ActionCable.Channel;

  constructor(
    private componentFactoryResolver: ComponentFactoryResolver,
    private viewContainerRef: ViewContainerRef) {
  }

  public ngOnInit(): void {
    this.cable = ActionCable.createConsumer('wss://<my-heroku-app>.herokuapp.com/cable');
    this.subscription = this.cable.subscriptions.create(
      'RoomChannel',
      {
         connected: this.connected,
         disconnected: this.disconnected,
         received: this.received,
      });
   }

  private showMessage(messageString) {
    if (!this.messageRef) {
      const messageComponent = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(MessageComponent);
      this.messageRef = this.message.createComponent(messageComponent);
    }
    this.messageRef.instance.message = messageString;
    this.messageRef.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();
  }

  private connected() {
    console.log('connected!');
  }

  private disconnected() {
    console.log('disconnected!');
  }

  private received(data: any) {
    console.log('received');
    // What do I put here? `this` is of type Subscription, 
    // and thus, I can't call `this.showMessage(data.message)`
  }
}
```

I want to use some sort of predicate or inject something into that context (sorry if I'm not using the right terminology), but I am just not sure how to do this.  I plan on cleaning things up instead of having this all in the `AppComponent` class, but for now I'm just trying to learn.

Any ideas?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The answer seems to be this:

```
this.cable = ActionCable.createConsumer(this.url)
this.subscription = this.cable.subscriptions.create(
  'RoomChannel',
  {
    connected: this.connected,
    disconnected: this.disconnected,
    // The key here, apparently, is to use a fat-arrow
    // function so that the `this` I care about is
    // lexicographically scoped.  I still need to better
    // understand what exactly that means, but I have a
    // general idea.
    received: (data) => this.received(data)
  });
```